# Combine object data with an array of objects

Tags: javascript

By making two API calls receive **two types** of data as follows:

First, array of objects:

```
[
  { label: "Private", price: 5 },
  { label: "VIP", price: 5 },
];
```

Second, a plain object used as dictionary/map:

```
{
    "Private": {
        "count": 34
    },
    "VIP": {
        "count": 80
    }
}
```

How do I merge this data depending on the label to get the following result:

```
[
  { label: "Private", price: 5, count: 34 },
  { label: "VIP", price: 5, count: 80 },
]
```

Comment: please add your code. where is the problem?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: usually op adds some code and ask for trouble shooting with the given code. actually it reads like 'give me the code' ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small approach with looking for label in `counts`.

```js
const
    data = [{ label: "Private", price: 5 }, { label: "VIP", price: 5 }],
    counts = { Private: { count: 34 }, VIP: { count: 80 } },
    result = data.map(o => ({ ...o, ...counts[o.label] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge data from 2 API actually depends on the labelling, and you need to acquire the second data.
you mentioned the second type of data is an object but no structure was provided
Assuming is something like this:-
{
"Private": 32,
"VIP": 78
}

You can do this to achieve your aim of merging:-

```
const arrayData = [
  { label: "Private", price: 5 },
  { label: "VIP", price: 5 },
];

const objectData = {
  "Private": 32,
  "VIP": 78
};

const mergedData = arrayData.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  count: objectData[item.label] || 0
}));

console.log(mergedData);
```